# How to get the iterator of 2d native array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, iterator

At the beginning I am looking for a way to initial the entire array into one specific value.
Although I know `memset()` in `<cstring>` can do this, I want to make it by a more C++ way.

Then I get to know `std::fill()` can be a way to do with single dimension array

```
const int SIZE = 10;
int arr[SIZE];
std::fill(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 1);
```

But this doesn't work when with 2d or multi-dimension array.
How can I get the iterator of multi-dimension array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: small remark: std::fill sets each member to the specified value, memset fills each byte with the value, so for ints you can only set them if each byte has the same value (e.g. 0xFFFFFFFF, meaning -1 in 2's complement)

Comment: @stefaanv Yes I know this, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2D arrays are contiguous in memory, so you can do

```
int arr[ROWS][COLS];
const size_t total_size = ROWS*COLS;
std::fill(&a[0][0], &a[0][0]+ total_size, 1);
```

where `total_size` is the total number of elements.

Comment: you have to be carefull that the array really is an multidimentional array and not an array of pointers to another array. access looks syntactical the same but memory layout is completely different of course.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks a lot! And What I would like to add is to get the total_size `const int total_size = sizeof arr / 4;`

Comment: @JanFan: if you wnat to use `sizeof`, use `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)`.